# WPF DataGrid Data Disappearing

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am loading a data grid in the `InitializeComponent()` method of my xaml window. I am noticing that the grid loads but then the data disappears. Stepping through the code I am not clearing the Observable Collection that the grid is bound to but the data is still disappearing. Incidentally when the grid is repopulated upon DatePicker selection the grid data stays but.

```
dtpkrMondaysDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;

...

weatherList = weatherCollections.GetWeeksWeather(
    Convert.ToDateTime(
        dtpkrMondaysDate.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString()
    )
);
dgForecastWeater.ItemsSource = weatherList;
```

Comment: Well, if you don't clear the `weatherList` somewhere in your code, then probably somewhere you set `dgForecastWeater.ItemsSource` to another (empty) collection or `null`. Do you have a data binding on `dgForecastWeater.ItemsSource` in your XAML perhaps? I can't tell because i can't see your code. Please check anything that possibly touches `dgForecastWeater.ItemsSource` in some way. Another thing to check: Is it just the content of the DataGrid that disappears, or is the DataGrid control itself becoming invisible or collapsed?

Comment: So, yeah, if I remove the ItemsSource={Binding weatherList} from the xaml it works fine. If I leave the xaml binding reference and delete the ItemsSource set to my Observable Collection then I get no data. I need to go back to data binding school. :(

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
Or at least a workaround.

Datagrid binding mode was set to TwoWay.
I set this to OneWay FROM source and we're good.
User's will not need to alter or add data so this works.

Still a little puzzling, though.

Comment: Don't use both a binding against `ItemsSource` and `ItemsSource` assignment in your code. Only do one of those things (preferably keep the binding, and get rid of the `ItemsSource` assignment in code-behind)

Comment: See comment above.